# What subalgebras does the exceptional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_2$ have?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am currently working on my bachelors thesis, which is about classifying the (maximal) subgroups of the compact real form $G_2$. So far, using Borel and de Siebenthal theory, I have identified $\mathfrak{su}(3)$ and $\mathfrak{su}(2) \times \mathfrak{su}(2)$ as subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}_2$. I am pretty sure that $\mathfrak{su}(2) = \mathfrak{so}(3) $ itself is also a subalgebra of  $\mathfrak{g}_2$. 
My question is, if there are any more? Are there any more subalgebras of $\mathfrak{g}_2$ or subgroups of $G_2$? I dont need a proof, I just want to know how much more work is ahead of me, and I can't really find any complete lists for this topic. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends on the "equivalence" of subalgebras you want to consider. For a classification up to "linear equivalence" see de Graaf's [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.1972.pdf) and the references therein

Comment: I've found that paper aswell, I can't really answer my question with it. Linear equivalence and equivalence conicide for the $\mathfrak{g}_2$. As I've said, I do not really need to know how to arrive there, I just want to know what subalgebras there are. A simple enumeration would be absolutely fine.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted the subalgebras only up to isomorphism. This would be much easier.